# opengl - texture clamping not working in post processing

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm having a problem with post processing in my deferred renderer.
When I'm applying an effect like bloom on top of my scene, the bottom of the bloom effect texture leaks into the top of my screen, the top of the texture leaks into the bottom of the screen, the left into the right of the screen and so on.
Looks like the uv coords don't get clamped correctly, although I thought I'd have set that all correctly.

The bloom effect in this case is created in a lower resolution and the gets upsampled using linear filtering.

This image that shows the problem:

[image]

I render the postprocessing effects using a simple quad:

```
glm::vec3(-1.f, -1.f, 0.f),
glm::vec3(1.f, -1.f, 0.f),
glm::vec3(1.f, 1.f, 0.f),
glm::vec3(-1.f, 1.f, 0.f)
```

This is the vertex shader I use to render the quad:

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 POSITION;

noperspective out vec2 tex_coord;

void main(void)
{
    tex_coord = POSITION.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;

    gl_Position = vec4(POSITION.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And if course in the fragment shader I'm doing something like this:

```
#version 430 core

uniform sampler2D uTexture;

noperspective in vec2 tex_coord;

out vec4 frag_color;

void main(void)
{
    frag_color = texture(uTexture, tex_coord);
}
```

The effect got rendered into a frame buffer object which got set up like this:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_filterFbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _filterFbo);

// filter texture
glGenTextures(1, &_filterTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _filterTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, _effectWidth, _effectHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _filterTexture, 0);
```

I really don't know what's the problem here, I hope anyone got an idea.

Comment: From what you have shown, I do not see anything that stands out as being incorrect. This might help you since you mentioned doing Bloom effect with a deferred shader; however this tutorial page website I'm about to show you has a full 3D scene rendered with lighting and normal as well as using multiple shader programs. It should serve as an excellent guide as into how the Bloom Effect can be achieved along with some variants of it.  http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Bloom

Comment: thanks for the link! I got the solution to my problem meanwhile, it was just a typo.. I clamped to GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY instead of GL_TEXTURE_2D

Comment: That is good that you found the mistake. I'm surprised I didn't notice that myself.